# Format string Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Need some help with string formatting.

User copy/paste his resume to textarea from document which could be work, pdf, text  and submit. Resume might have bullets or some special characters.

Application uses **spring MVC** and i am seeing the below error as soon as its submitted

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [java.lang.IntegerEditor] found for type java.lang.Integer according to 'Editor' suffix convention
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [java.lang.StringEditor] found for type java.lang.String according to 'Editor' suffix convention
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

can any one suggest how fix this issue or convert it into plain text.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please precise spring version and show you controller code. And have you a custom `ConversionService` anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

Its directly related to missing jars, As per below code you are missing jar to inclucde it in your class path.

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("No property editor [" + editorName + "] found for type " +
                        targetType.getName() + " according to 'Editor' suffix convention");
            }
            unknownEditorTypes.put(targetType, Boolean.TRUE);
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: i thought the same but when i submit the resume with no bullets the resume goes through. Otherwise it goes a custom redirect page and log stops at the above mentioned lines

Comment: Can you try the below one ==== CustomEditorConfigurer configures the propertyeditors used for loading the application context. It does NOT configure the propertyeditors used by the controllers.

Inject your PropertyEditorRegistrar into your controller.

Comment: Its applicable only if you using any customeditor, If you are not using any customeditor then not required.

Comment: i am not using editor. As soon as its submit it does serverside validation which implements validator